# Set maximum image resolution for PickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want take a image with a fixed resolution. The user need to be forced for crop the image. I need a square image.

I'am using next code and it just crop by width screen resolution.

```
self.imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.imagepicker.delegate = self;
self.imagepicker.allowsEditing=YES;
self.imagepicker.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

self.imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:self.imagepicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What problem you are facing by this code ?

Comment: you want to crop square image before set  image ?

Comment: i want the user cut the image how it wants, but when the image is landscape and he dont zoom image, the image will have a black bar top and down

Comment: set allows editing to NO, and write your own method to crop the image!!!

Answer (score 1):

`preferredContentSize` is not a property of the UIImagePickerController itself, but of any UIViewController, for when it is embedded in a UIPopoverController.

You'll need to present a cropping interface yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to done after selecting image please try this code for crop image in center

```
- (UIImage *)squareImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGFloat)newSize1
{
    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform;
    CGPoint origin;
    CGFloat newSize;

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height)
    {
        newSize=image.size.height;
        CGFloat scaleRatio = newSize / image.size.height;
        scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        origin = CGPointMake(-(image.size.width - image.size.height) / 2.0f, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=image.size.width;
        CGFloat scaleRatio = newSize / image.size.width;
        scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        origin = CGPointMake(0, -(image.size.height - image.size.width) / 2.0f);
    }

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(newSize, newSize);
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, scaleTransform);

    [image drawAtPoint:origin];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Its helpful to you. Thanks